# ASP.Net MVC 4 not accepting hyphen in form input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form with a text input defined as follows

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
                    <td align="left" style="font-size:Medium;width:400px;">@Html.TextBox("sn", "", new { @style = "font-size:Medium;width:400px;", @class = "fnTxtBox"  })
</td>
    }
```

The user needs to be able to include a hyphen ('-') in the text box, e.g. ##-######, but ASP.Net MVC doesn't just marks the textbox red if I try to include it, if I remove the hyphen the form get posted as normal.  Including hyphens as input is an absolute requirement by my client, is there an option to enable this? Why is the hyphen getting rejected??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the `fnTxtBox` css class used for?

Comment: fnTxtBox is just a stub class for some jQuery to clear input from this text box when a user hits a button. The class is not referenced by anything else.